# Highlight all cells that contain a value in another cell

Tags: excel

I am using Excel

I would like to hihglight every cell in a spreadsheet that contains (Case-Insensitive) the value entered in another cell.

I have been playing around with conditional formating but I have not found success.

Comment: Use an =IF() statement to compare the two cells.  You could then apply conditional formatting to the output.

Comment: Conditional formatting has a built-in "highlight duplicates" option.

Comment: Ok thanks, I got the answer on another post. Use this formula: =SUM(COUNTIF(A4,"*" & $A$2 & "*")) = 1

Answer (score 0):

This small macro uses the value found in cell **A1** and hi-lights any cell containing that value:

```
Sub ColorCells()
    Dim s As String, r As Range
    s = Range("A1").Text
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If InStr(1, r.Text, s) > 0 Then
            r.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel treats a *0* (*zero*) as FALSE. By strict definition, anything that is not FALSE is TRUE. Conditional formatting rules based upon a formula are only looking for a TRUE or FALSE; anything more than that is superfluous. The formula you described in the comments section of your original question could be pared down to,

`=COUNTIF(A4,"*" & $A$2 & "*")`

Another method for case insensitive search is to see if `SEARCH` returns a position (e.g. it was found) or an error (e.g. it was not found).

`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2, A4))`

This can optionally be turned into a case-sensitive search by swapping out `SEARCH` for `FIND`.

`=ISNUMBER(FIND($A$2, A4))`